# How to populate many the same shapes (rectangles) with Custom Painter (Flutter) in faster way

Tags: flutter, paint, drawrectangle

**MyPainter class**

```
class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
     Paint _paint;

    **Constructor**

     MyPainter(){
       _paint = Paint()
       ..color = Colors.indigo;

     }


     @override
      void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size){
```

**draw one rectangle (size, color, style)**

```
       var rect1 = Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 20.0,20.0);
```

**color**

```
       _paint.color = Color(0xffACCAF6);
```

**style**

```
       _paint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;
```

**draw rectangle**

```
       canvas.drawRect(rect1, _paint);
     }
```

**bool shouldRepaint**

```
      @override
      bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate)
       return oldDelegate != this;
      }
    }
```

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odP9g.jpg)

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually? what exactly do you want to draw in your `CustomPainter`?

Comment: I want to draw many rectangles in the container for example 20 x 20

Comment: so use `Canvas.drawRect` inside a [0..20*20-1] range loop - you cannot draw all of them in one `Canvas` method call

Comment: Could you write an example, How to code it?

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < 20 * 20; i++) { var row = i ~/ 20; var col = i % 20; ...`

Comment: I don't get the required result :( In this way, I can only create one shape, my goal is to create many of the same shapes as a chessboard (but with the same color shapes).

Comment: post your whole code then

Comment: ''' @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size){
   for (var i = 0; i < 20 *20; i++){
     var rect1 = Rect.fromLTWH((i/20), (i%20).toDouble(), 20.0,20.0);
   _paint.color = Color(0xffACCAF6);
   _paint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;
   canvas.drawRect(rect1, _paint);

   }'''

Comment: Thank you for the help:) I get the required result, in this way: Container(
        child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 15,
          children: List.generate(405, (index) {
            return MyPaint();
          }),
        ),
      ),